# unable to get json data to jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I have some Json data which I got from sql server by querying the database. The data was serialized to json using java script serializer. But Im unable to bind the Json Data to jQuery datatables.i checked my json file it seems fine but i don't know where is it the problem.

Here is my javascript code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "ajax": "/data.json",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "CodeAgence" },
            { "data": "NomConseillerPrevu" },
            { "data": "PrenomConseillerPrevu" },
            { "data": "CodeConseillerPrevu" }
            
        ],
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": -1,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": "<button>Click!</button>"
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe JavaScript will read data in from a file on the local file system (e.g. 'C:\').

You'll need to load it from a web request by putting the data file in the web root for example and using:

```
"ajax": "/Data.json",
```

See https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/index.html for more info on data sources

Comment: i added it in my project (web project)@ChrisWhheeler